# jQuery inArray verification problems

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, conditional-statements

My inArray jQuery verification dosen't work :

The html :

```
<input type="text" name="number" class="verify" conditions="requierd numeric"/>
<input type="text" name="number2" class="verify" conditions="requierd string"/>
```

The jQuery code with my inArray verification :

```
    $('input.verify').blur(function(){
        var conditions = $(this).attr('conditions').split(' ');
            if($.inArray('requierd', conditions)){
                alert('ok');
            }
    });
```

but when i put `=== false` behind my condition it work !

```
    $('input.verify').blur(function(){
        var conditions = $(this).attr('conditions').split(' ');
            if($.inArray('requierd', conditions) === false){
                alert('ok');
            }
    });
```

Why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) says:

> returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.
>
> Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1.

Answer (score 0):

Like with `indexOf()`, `$.inArray` must be checked against `-1`. Otherwise, if the element is not found, it will return `-1` which i s a *truthy* value, i.e. it will resolve your condition to true.

In short:

```
if ($.inArray('something', array) != -1)
```

Note though that you don't really need to split the conditions string - you could use a REGEX with a word boundary.

```
if (/\brequired\b/.test($(this).attr('conditions')) { /* code */ }
```

Finally, you should use `data-` attributes rather than just inventing custom attributes, as the latter will invalidate your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

[`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) will return `-1` if the element is not found, which will evaluate to `true`. Either use:

```
if (~$.inArray('requierd', conditions))
```

This will work because `~-1 == 0 == false`. Or, as an alternative, and by far the most common:

```
if ($.inArray('requierd', conditions) != -1)
```